# Can Scala.js generate TypeScript d.ts type bindings?

Tags: javascript, typescript, scala, scala.js

I'd like to use Scala.js to write libraries to then use in web applications written in TypeScript. This requires TypeScript type bindings (*.d.ts file) to be generated by Scala.js for my library. Does Scala.js support this?

Comment: Old but you can have a look at [Scala-TS](https://scala-ts.github.io/scala-ts/) (I'm a contributor of)

Comment: thanks! https://github.com/scala-ts/scala-ts is cool. imo, the Scala and Scala.js communities have done a terrible job integrating JS libraries written in Scala into the broader JS ecosystem. Scala should be an extremely popular web language, instead it's insular and niche.

Answer (score 2):

No, Scala.js currently does not support this.

See Scala.js issue [#3836](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/3836) for potential follow-up and updates.